# how to set header alignment of datagrid in flash by action script 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, datagrid

this is my code, but it didn`t work! any idea?:

```
var dg_format2:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
dg_format2.color = "0xFFFFFF";
dg_format2.size=15;
dg_format2.font = "B Yekan";
dg_format2.align="center";
users_data_grid.setStyle("headerTextFormat",dg_format2);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful, when asking this question, to specify what kind of datagrid you are using. In the Flex world there are at least three: 
 - mx.controls.DataGrid
 - mx.controls.AdvancedDataGrid
 - spark.components.DataGrid

It looks as though your style name may be wrong. None of these three types of data grid has a 'headerTextFormat' style.

Which type of datagrid are you using?

Comment: The term "Flex" has different meanings in front end development. It can be used to refer to the use of HTML "FlexBox" CSS. In the Flash world it can be used to refer to Apache Flex which is an ActionScript library.

I may be mistaken, but the use of 'setStyle()' gives me the impression that this is Apache Flex code, and that 'user_data_grid' an instance of a subclass of the Flex UIComponent class, from which it inherits setStyle().

Could you show the line of code where you instantiate user_data_grid, and the import statement that imports the class that you are creating an instance of?

Comment: Mc Carroll I just drag and drop DataGrid from components to the timeline.

Comment: Oh, I see. It looks as though the 'components' functionality in Flash uses underlying code that is similar to, but not the same as, Flex. I'm sorry to say that I don't know enough about this to be helpful, as I just code in Flex and don't use Flash.